# Обрезка строки Spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть spinner, содержащий длинноватые строки. Можно ли выводить выбранную строку урезанной? То есть я из списка выбираю длинную строку, а в закрытом спиннере выбранная строка отображается укороченной.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: выставьте максимальную длинну TextView, который служит элементом списка для спиннера.

Comment: оно начинает в несколько строк выводить

Comment: Атрибуты `android:singleLine`, `android:maxLines`, `android:ellipsize` вам в помощь.

Comment: я в курсе про них, но ни одного у spinner`а не нашел

Comment: @SlowAR, значит, как сказал @metalurgus, применяйте эти атрибуты к

>TextView, который служит элементом списка для спиннера.

На крайний случай в адаптере можно захардкодить обрезку строки.

Comment: @SlowAR, эти атрибуты есть у TextView, который является элементом списка для Spinner.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в разметку вашего **spinner**(a) следующие строки:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Описание:

- **maxLines** - строго указывает сколько строчек будет в виджете
- **ellipsize** - обрежет строку, если она не вмешается в одну строку и в конце поставит "..."

Надеюсь вам помогло мое решение!